# Selenium with Python automation script nested if loop not working

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to run a script that will go through a page and sequentially click on every instance there is a giveaway. Some giveaway pages have two check boxes, and some have one. I need to be able to have the ability to pass through a page where there is either one or two.

Furthermore, I need this to be able to loop as many times as needed on each page and then proceed onto the next page of giveaways (there are many pages). I did not include this part in the code yet. I am not sure how to determine how many pages to click through and then repeat the first part (entering each giveaway).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#start new browser session
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='O:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe')

browser.set_page_load_timeout(20)

#navigating to webpage
browser.get('https://www.example.com')

#sign in
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In').click()
browser.find_element_by_name("user[email]").send_keys('user@email.com')
browser.find_element_by_name("user[password]").send_keys('password')
browser.find_element_by_name('next').click()

#enter giveaways on page
enter = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Enter Giveaway')
for x in range(0,len(enter)):
if enter[x].is_displayed():
    enter[x].click()
    #click on giveaway criteria etc
    browser.find_element_by_link_text('Select This Address').click()
    browser.find_element_by_name("entry_terms").click()
    browser.find_element_by_name("want_to_read").click()
    browser.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
    #start back at giveaway list
    browser.get('https://www.example.com')
```

I also had played around with some other for/if options that didn't work:

```
enter = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Enter Giveaway')
for x in range(0,len(enter)):
if enter[x].is_displayed():
    enter[x].click()
    browser.find_element_by_link_text('Select This Address').click()
    browser.find_element_by_name("entry_terms").click()
    wtr = browser.find_element_by_name("want_to_read")
    if wtr.is_displayed():
        browser.find_element_by_name("want_to_read").click()
        else:
            browser.find_element_by_name("commit").click()        
    browser.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
    browser.get('https://www.example.com')
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Do I need to use `while` instead? Or do I need to do an `assert` for this? I am not sure where to proceed. I have looked at many other questions on Stack Overflow but none seem to help.

Here is the output (I am not sure if I have other errors for each version of the script but this is the most recent?):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "o:\PycharmProjects\pytest\testTwo_nestedIf.py", line 27, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_name("want_to_read").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 487, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"want_to_read"}
```